# Adding new row at the end of DataGridView in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm using a for loop to list my .txt files item on DataGridView element but when i tested with a basic code i realize it's adding new rows from the top because of that only the last item listed on DataGridView.

```
 Public Shared Sub TestCode()
        For i = 0 To 6

            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = "This is: " & i
            Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(Me.DataGridView1.RowCount - 1)
            Me.DataGridView1.Update()
        Next
 End Sub
```

How is it possible to adding/inserting new rows at the bottom.

Comment: That code can't even compile so how could it be adding rows anywhere? If you want to add a row then look at the `Add` method of the `Rows` collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last row in datagridview is to allow user to add row if he wants.
Set `DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False`

Then try to use  `Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add()` . 
It will add a new row at the end of the dataGridView

**or**

try this `dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1, row);`